# Cron and launchd rsync/ssh job do not work when screen is locked

Tags: macos, ssh, launchd, cron, rsync

I have implemented a bash script to perform a backup to a remote server over ssh using rsync. Running the script in the terminal works correctly. I then scheduled a crontab job to run this script twice a week. When I'm logged in, with the screen unlocked, the job runs correctly at the specified time. However, if the screen is locked some bash commands before the rsync run correctly, but then the rsync connection fails:

```
xxxxx [33786] rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(231) [sender=3.2.7]
xxxxx [33804] rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
```

I also scheduled it using `launchd` and the behavior is the same. Searching a bit I found this might be related to the ssh connection not working when the screen is locked. How can make ssh to work, either with crontab or launchd, even when the screen is locked?

In case is useful information I did have to add this in the bash script to make it work with the ssh agent:

```
declare -x SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$( ls /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.*/Listeners )`
```

The MacOS version I'm using is Mojave 10.14.6. Thank you.

Comment: I've had lots of problems trying to get Mojave (and other macOS) maintain an SSH connection during sleep state. Do you have a copy of `LaunchControl` on Mojave? If so, have you tried scheduling your job as a *'System Daemon'*? If not, you might try using `caffeinate` to maintain the SSH connection; á la `caffeinate -s ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o ServerAliveCountMax=10 username@hostname`. The `caffeinate` thing seems to work intermittently... I think the fundamental problem is in macOS.

Comment: The system is not in sleep state, only the screen is locked. But I'm not sure what is the effect of locked screen on background processes. My bash script has some commands like `find`, and `echo` writing to a text file, and those commands run correctly. Is only the `ssh` connection that seems to be not working when the screen is locked. Thanks for the suggestion, I will try both scheduling it as a 'System Daemon' and `caffeinate`.